# fatal error: 'libavcodec/avcodec.h' file not found caused by zergon321/reisen

Tags: go, libav, libavcodec

When running Go code on Mac M2 (important, because installation of related libs work differently on Linux)  that imports "github.com/zergon321/reisen" I got this:

```
# github.com/zergon321/reisen
/Users/ido/go/pkg/mod/github.com/zergon321/reisen@v0.1.4/audio.go:4:11: fatal error: 'libavcodec/avcodec.h' file not found
 #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I have ffmpeg (includes the libavcodec/avcodec.h header) installed using brew

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

but it doesn't get picked up by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked to fix it:

1. If you indeed installed `ffmpeg` with brew, the header file should be there -> `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h` (lib version could be different).
   If it is not there for some reason, you can try to locate the header file using `find / -name "avcodec.h"`
2. Once you have established `avcodec.h`'s location, note the full path to the `/include` directory and run your go code passing the following flag:

```
CGO_CPPFLAGS="-I<path/to/include/directory>" go run <your file name or a period>
```

The full command for me looked like this:

```
CGO_CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/include" go run .
```