# ld: library not found for -lavutil caused by zergon321/reisen on Mac M2

Tags: go, ffmpeg, libav

Command:

```
CGO_CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/include" go run .
```

Output:

```
# github.com/zergon321/reisen
cgo-gcc-prolog:114:35: warning: 'swr_alloc_set_opts' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/include/libswresample/swresample.h:259:1: note: 'swr_alloc_set_opts' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/include/libavutil/attributes.h:100:49: note: expanded from macro 'attribute_deprecated'
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
ld: library not found for -lavutil
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Context:

- trying to run Go code that imports `"github.com/zergon321/reisen"` on Mac M2
- solved the previous header issue - [not being able to find libavcodec/avcodec.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74208773/fatal-error-libavcodec-avcodec-h-file-not-found-caused-by-zergon321-reisen)
- have `libavutil` installed in the same location as libavcodec - `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/include` so should be also picked up by the CGO_CPPFLAGS.

Could it be the deprecation warning for `libavutil` (see above)?